# How to set a LDAP client-requested size limit in Java?

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

[An article about best practices in LDAP searches](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html) states:

> Programmers should always provide a client-requested size limit.

How can this be done in Java? I can not find any appropriate option the in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap.html).

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

If the client is using the UnboundID LDAP SDK:

```
SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest(baseObject,scope,filter,requestedAttributes);
req.setSizeLimit(maxNumberOfEntriesToReturn);
```

If the client is using JNDI, use `setCountLimit`, and consider using the UnboundID LDAP SDK instead of JNDI for new code.

Comment: I am using `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)` from Oracle.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference what version. JNDI had been built into Java for over ten years, and the API has hardly changed at all in that time.

Comment: @EJP But the UnboundID LDAP SDK seems to be an replacement for JNDI, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

.setSizeLimit() does not help to enlange server-size limit.

and this code also

```
                SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
                ctls.setCountLimit(99000);
```

You should use paging mode.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    int count = 0;
    LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection("hostname", 389, "user@domain", "password");

    final String path = "OU=Users,DC=org,DC=com";
    String[] attributes = {"SamAccountName","name"};

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(path, SearchScope.SUB, Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass", "person"), attributes);

    ASN1OctetString resumeCookie = null;
    while (true)
    {
        searchRequest.setControls(
                new SimplePagedResultsControl(100, resumeCookie));
        SearchResult searchResult = connection.search(searchRequest);
        for (SearchResultEntry e : searchResult.getSearchEntries())
        {
            if (e.hasAttribute("SamAccountName"))
                System.out.print(count++ + ": " + e.getAttributeValue("SamAccountName"));

            if (e.hasAttribute("name"))
                System.out.println("->" + e.getAttributeValue("name"));
        }

        LDAPTestUtils.assertHasControl(searchResult,
                SimplePagedResultsControl.PAGED_RESULTS_OID);
        SimplePagedResultsControl responseControl =
                SimplePagedResultsControl.get(searchResult);
        if (responseControl.moreResultsToReturn())
        {
            resumeCookie = responseControl.getCookie();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

}